# Dialing a phone number in android with phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm writing an app using Phonegap. In my app I need to open the native android dialer. I'm using:

```
document.location = 'tel:' + NumToDial;
```

However, is it possible to have it auto-dial without requiring the user to click dial on the native android dialer?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not (ordinarily) possible, because of security restrictions.

Regular apps are not allowed to use the ACTION_CALL Intent.  It's restricted to prevent unscrupulous apps from, say, auto-dialing a 1-900 number and costing the user money.

Only system apps (that is, those that come pre-installed on the device) have access to ACTION_CALL.

Non-system apps have to settle for opening the dialer.